# How to append a List in Neo4j python-embedded?

Tags: python, list, neo4j

I'm trying to make a graph in Neo4j python-embedded using these docs:
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/python-embedded-reference-core.html
"Allowed property values include strings, numbers, booleans, as well as arrays of those primitives". So, I'm trying to build a list of strings, and then append the list.

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
db = GraphDatabase('/home/username/Neo4j/')
with db.transaction:
    testNode = db.node()
    testNode['stringList'] = ["one","two"]
    string_list_edit = testNode['stringList']
    string_list_edit.append("three")
```

Gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'java.lang.String[]' object has no attribute 'append'
```

How is this done?

Comment: testNode['stringList']+=["three"] works, but I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

If you paste all of your code, it's possible to evaluate it for other errors. Check out the docs: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/python-embedded-reference-core.html

Are you including?

```
with db.transactions:
```

Before your code? You must do that. Also, try this:

```
testNode['stringList'] = ["one","two"]
string_list_edit = testNode['stringList']
string_list_edit.append("three")
testNode['stringList'] = string_list_edit
```

Comment: with db.transactions is required. From the docs:"All write operations to the database need to be performed from within transactions. This ensures that your database never ends up in an inconsistent state."

Comment: I worded my answer poorly, I meant to say to make sure to include it, and if you are, try the following. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error says it all. That object doesn't have an `append()` method.

Why? My first thought is that it's a bridge object ("java.lang.String[]" is the String array type in Java) to handle conversions between Java and Python, and not a real Python list. Try making it a list

```
string_list_edit = list(testNode['stringList'])
string_list_edit.append("three")
```

Hopefully, setting it will still work the same way.

I don't think `+=` is *quite* the same as append in Python- when you're not using lists, I believe `+=` literally means `string_list_edit = string_list_edit + "three"` or maybe `string_list_edit = string_list_edit + ["three"]` which I could see working with the weird bridge object.

An easy way to confirm the bridge object theory- try a `print type(testNode['stringList'])` or similar.

Comment: @user890477, did this help at all?

Comment: not much :( that snippet gave me the same errors. I decided to build the entire list in python first. I also switched to the REST client instead, avoiding java forever :)

Comment: just downloaded your lucene-querybuilder. Thanks for all the great work!

Comment: Ha, welcome. lucene-querybuilder was mostly our intern, though :)